# Changed / is changed?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I have already searched some questions such as

["has changed" or "had changed" or "was changed"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/489554/has-changed-or-had-changed-or-was-changed)

["Has been changed" or "has changed"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97243/has-been-changed-or-has-changed)

But I am still confused.
If there is a sentence like

1. My wallet is changed.
2. My wallet changed.

Which one is correct?
Can both be correct?

Comment: One *changed* is being used adjectivally, and the other as a regular verb. They mean different things, but are both grammatical.

Comment: ... Rather, although the examples seem quirky, 'my wallet is changed' _may_ mean 'my wallet is [somehow] different' but can also mean 'my wallet is exchanged', the transformational passive. 'I go to the counter, showing them the broken zip, and without any fuss, my wallet is changed.'